# Min-Cost-Flow Problem

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, network-flow

Given a directed graph $G = (V,E)$ with a cost function $\gamma: E \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ and two vertices $u,v \in V$.

How to reduce the problem of finding a directed path from $u$ to $v$ with minimum cost to the Min-Cost-Flow Problem with some capacity, demand, cost functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. Create $G'$ as follows:

   - For any $w \in V$ create two vertices $w_\text{in}$ and $w_\text{out}$. Connect them with an edge of zero cost.
   - For any $e \in E$ create two vertices $e_\text{in}$ and $e_\text{out}$. Connect them with an edge of zero cost.
   - For any $e = (w \to w') \in E$ add edges $\{w_\text{out},e_\text{in}\}$ and $\{e_\text{out}, w'_\text{in}\}$ both of cost $\frac{1}{2}\gamma(e)$.
   - Remove $u_\text{in}$ and $v_\text{out}$.
2. Why is $G'$ bipartite?
3. Using min-cost-flow find the min-cost perfect matching in $G'$.
4. Why any perfect matching in $G'$ indicates a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$?
5. What happens if there is no path $u \to^* v$ in $G$?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I have some questions. $->^*$ means that? How about demand function and two capacity functions on $G'$?

Comment: Here $u \to^* v$ means there's just a path of any length from $u$ to $v$ (formally it's the reflexive-transitive closure of the edge relation). Why would you need two capacity functions?

Comment: I found some books saying that Min-Cost-Flow Problem has two capacity functions. So I think $G'$ needs them. Is there wrong in my knowledge?

Comment: @user129982 There are multiple versions of flow problems. Some of them include flow lower bounds beside the usual upper bounds (capacities). Others allow for directed network, which would make the reduction even simpler. However, as you didn't specified what min-cost flow you want, I used the most simple thing I could. In particular, the min-cost-perfect matching problem can by solved by any flow algorithm that would be described just by "min-cost flow".